# PHP 5.3: Function split() is deprecated

Tags: php

При переходе на php 5.3 появилась ошибка:

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /recordings/includes/bootstrap.php on line 235

при изменении split на explode пишет следующее:

> PHP PEAR must be installed. Visit
> http://pear.php.net for help with
> installation.

Comment: Ну `deprecated` -- не ошибка, а использование "нежелательной" функции. А вот то, что cookie пытаетесь выводить слишком поздно (когда заголовки уже закончились, и пошло тело ответа -- это ошибка.

Comment: c кукие решил php.ini поставил output_buffering в "On", осталась ошибка split (нежелательная функция)

Comment: строка на которую ругается выглядит так:  $buf = split(':|,',$include_path);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1. Установить PEAR и использовать все-таки explode

Вариант 2. Использовать медленный split, а в PHP.INI установить

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Но это не решение проблемы.

Вариант 3. Извратиться и написать свой explode:

```
if (!function_exists('explode')) {
     function explode( $delimiter , $string){
         if ($delimiter == "") return false;
         $len = strlen($string);
         $dellen = strlen($delimiter);
         $last = 0;
         $result = Array();
         for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i ++){
             if($i === $len - 1 && $last !== 0) 
                $result[] = substr($string, $last, $i - $last + 1);
             else if(substr($string, $i, $dellen) == $delimiter){
                 $result[] = substr($string, $last, $i - $last);
                 $last = $i + $dellen;
             }
         }
         return $result;
     }
}
```